# How do you add a controllable graphic with an image overtop in kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

I am new to python and have messed around with Kivy a little. This is the first app of my own design I've been tying to make. The goal is for it to be a game where there is a character that moves in all directions around the screen. My problem right now is that I can't get the character widget to display and I don't know if it's a problem with the widget or the image in the widget. When I run the program all I get is a black screen and no errors. Can anyone see where I went wrong?

Also if you have any recommendations in a better way to structure anything it would be appreciated :)

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.7.2')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle, Color, Canvas
from kivy.uix.image import Image




class WidgetDrawer(Widget):
    def __inti__(self, imageStr, **kwargs):
        super(WidgetDrawer,self).__inti__(**kwargs)
        with self.canvas:
            self.size = (Window.width*.05, Window.width*.05)
            self.x = self.center_x
            self.y = self.center_y
            self.pos = (self.x, self.y)
            self.rect_pl = Rectangle(source= imageStr, pos=self.pos, size=self.size)
            self.bind(pos=self.update_graphics_pos)
            self.rect_pl.pos = self.pos

    def update_graphic_pos(self, value):
        self.rect_pl.pos = value


    def setSize(self, width, height):
        self.size = (width,height)


class Player(WidgetDrawer):
    impulse_x = 3
    impulse_y = 3
    winre = -0.1
    velocity_x = NumericProperty(0) 
    velocity_y = NumericProperty(0)


    def move(self):
        self.x = self.x + self.velocity_x 
        self.y = self.y + self.velocity_y 

        if self.x > Window.width*.95 or self.x < Window.width*.05:
            velocity_x = 0
        if self.y > Window.height*.95 or self.y < Window.height*.05:
            velocity_y = 0

    def determineVelocity(self):
        self.velocity_x = self.impulse_x + self.winre
        self.velocity_y = self.impulse_y + self.winre

    def update(self):
        self.determineVelocity()
        self.move()



class GUI(Widget):
    def __init___(self, **kwargs):
        super(GUI, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.character = Player(imageStr = './character.png')
        self.character.x = Window.width/4
        self.character.y = Window.height/2
        self.add_widget(self.character)

class GameApp(App):
    def build(self):

        parent = Widget()

        app = GUI()
        parent.add_widget(app)  
        return parent

if __name__ == '__main__':
    GameApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `self.add_widget(self.character)` i.e. adding widget in `__init__` method. Try to run `python main.py -m inspector`, Ctrl+E and get to `GUI()`. No children, nothing. Add children after `__init__`.

About the structure:

- use [kv language](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html)
- use one [naming style](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles)
- fix typos(`__inti__` != `__init__`)
- if you have `1.7.2` version, you definitely need to update asap